# Mount point 0 does not exist

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, raspberrypi

I have been trying to mount an usb drive to my raspberry, but suddenly i started getting the same error over and over and I couldn't find a single way to fix this.

> mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 3 -- ignored
>   mount: mount point 0 does not exist

And this is the fstab file:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p6 /boot vfat defaults
0 2 /dev/mmcblk0p7 / ext4
defaults,noatime 0 1
#### a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#### use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
UUID=E6A0-4042 /media/usb1 auto nofail,uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime 0 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have messed up the entries in `/etc/fstab` getting the USB thumb to mount.

From what you have posted, the lines 2-3 do not look sane and should rather be merged to:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p6 /boot vfat defaults         0 2 
/dev/mmcblk0p7 /     ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
```